# Docker container not exposed on network

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am new to docker. I am running it on windows. I am trying to get a container named "ghost" (available from the Docker Hub) to work on a Windows 8.1 machine.  While the container starts correctly and supposedly exposes url at http://localhost:2368, when I enter this address nothing happens.  The same has happened when trying other containers from the Hub which expose urls.

I tried accessing the container's exposed URL from the IP Address I get from the "docker ip" but it failed too. I also tried running the container with the "--net="bridge"" option, to no avail. I think I'm missing something pretty basic, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Docker on Windows that means you most likely installed `boot2docker`.

`boot2docker` starts a minimal Linux VM (based on `VirtualBox`) because Docker requires a Linux kernel to run. The Docker daemon is started *on that VM* and not on your `localhost`.

You can determine the VMs IP address by typing `boot2docker ip` on your command line. The standard `boot2docker` IP address is `192.168.59.103` if you did not configure something else or have multiple instances of that VM running.

So when you execute `docker run --name ghost -p 2368:2368 -d ghost` the port `2368` is opened at `192.168.59.103:2368`. That is where you need to connect to.

For more information please read the [official `boot2docker` documentation](http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/).

Comment: I had actually come across this answer, and I had obtained the VMs ip address with "boot2docker ip", but I still couldn't connect. It seems that, even though you connect to the VM's IP, you still need to map the ports to expose them publicly. Unmapped ports are inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the complete 'docker run ...' command you executed, so I'm assuming you ran the one specified in the image's page on Docker Hub (reproduced below).

```
docker run --name some-ghost -p 8080:2368 -d ghost
```

The command is mapping Ghost's exposed port inside the container (2368) to port 8080 in your boot2docker VM. The first thing you need to do is run **boot2docker ip** to find out the IP address of your boot2docker VM. About the port number, you have two options:

- Access Ghost via port 8080 (http://BOOT2DOCKER-IP:8080)
- Change the port mapping to expose 2368 (-p 2368:2368)